# How to train a Keras model on GCP with fit_generator

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, google-cloud-platform

I have an ML model developed in Keras and I can train it locally by calling its `fit_generator` and providing it with my custom generator. Now I want to use GCP to train this model. I've been following [this article](https://medium.com/searce/creating-deep-learning-models-training-and-deploying-it-on-google-cloud-ml-engine-using-9a4ed6a84076) that shows how I can train a Keras model on GCP but it does not say what should I do if I need to load all my data into memory, process it and then feed it to the model through a generator.

Does anyone know how I can use GCP if I have a generator?

Answer (score 0):

In the example you are following, the Keras model gets converted into an [estimator](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/estimator), using the function `model_to_estimator`; this step is not necessary in order to use GCP, as GCP supports compiled Keras models. If you keep the model as a Keras model, you can call either its function `fit` (which supports the use of generators since TensorFlow 1.12) or `fit_generator` and pass them your generator as the first argument. If it works locally for you, then it should also be able to work in GCP. I have been able to run models in GCP similar to the one in the url you shared and using generators without any problems.

Also be advised that the `gcloud ml-engine` commands are being replaced by `gcloud ai-platform`. I recommend you follow [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/getting-started-keras), as it is more updated than the one you linked to.